# Instantiate singleton object using Class.forName()?

Tags: java, constructor, singleton, default, instance

I want to instantiate one instance of a class from the string
name of the class. ( using Class.forName().newInstance(). )

Here's the problem: I want that instance to be a singleton..
I could do this using a singleton pattern, except that
newInstance calls the default constructor for a class, 
and with a singleton, that constructor must be "private"..

Is there a solution? I could think of a less elegant way
to do this (using a hashmap as a lookup table..), but would prefer
a better solution..

Thanks,

Comment: I just read though your question twice and don't follow it... Perhaps others will but I thought I'd let you know...

Comment: FYI: http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-6623.pdf page 31.

Answer (score 8):

A classic singleton also has a static getInstance() method - call that via reflection instead of using newInstance(). Yeah, it's more work, but that's how it is...

Or you could use [setAccessible()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) to call the private constructor anyway, but you'd break the singleton and go to hell.

Thirdly, you could avoid having a Singleton altogether and find a better soltion (there usually is).

Answer (score 8):

You could use reflection to get a reference to a static factory method of the class, and then invoke that. The factory method could enforce the singleton pattern

```
Class c = Class.forName("test.MyClass");
Method factoryMethod = c.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
Object singleton = factoryMethod.invoke(null, null);
```

And then

```
public class MyClass {

   private static MyClass instance;

   private MyClass() { 
      // private c'tor 
   }

   public static synchronized MyClass getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new MyClass();
      }
      return instance:
   }
}
```

Warning: Singleton design pattern may be detrimental to your longterm health.

Comment: Nice, still I would like to know why the OP wants to have a singleton by name?

Comment: Maybe they're re-inventing Spring.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to know the method name of your singleton class that constructs the object.
If it's e.g. called "instance()" you can do something like

```
Class c = Class.forName("MySingleton");
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("instance",null);
MySingleton singleton = m.invoke(null,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum and have a HashMap named for each of them. Or you could use some dependency injection framework to get a singleton of something (Guice?)

**Edit** Okay, I jump in with a code sample too:

```
package tests;
public class EnumSingleton {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("tests.Singleton1");
        Operation instance = Operation.class.cast(c.getEnumConstants()[0]);
        System.out.println(instance.getTHEAnswer());

        c = Class.forName("tests.Singleton2");
        instance = Operation.class.cast(c.getEnumConstants()[0]);
        System.out.println(instance.getTHEAnswer());
    }
}
interface Operation {
    int getTHEAnswer();
}
enum Singleton1 implements Operation {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public int getTHEAnswer() {
        return 42;
    }
}
enum Singleton2 implements Operation {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public int getTHEAnswer() {
        return 84;
    }
}
```

And its safe and sound. **Edit** And has some meaning now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you instead rely upon the existence of a static factory method? It would rely upon some manner of naming convention, but that would work.

Bottom line: if a class is to be known to be singleton then it must have responsibility for that policing. Hence it must conform to some implementation of the pattern, and if you want a dynamic selection amongst such classes then you need to be able to predict the "Factory" approach.